# using recursive function with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, pass-by-reference, cs50

I'm trying to do an exercise for recursive function and am trying to apply my new knowledge of pointers. The exercise asks us to use the Collatz Conjecture to get any positive number back to one, but it asks to count the steps from that number to 1

The algorithm is as follows:

- if n == 1 stop
- if n is even then repeat this process on n/2
- if n is odd the repeat this process on (n*3)+1

Here is my attempt to declare an int counter and pass it by reference to the function so we can count how many steps it took to count back to 1:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void collatz (int n, int *counter);

int main (void)
{
    printf("n:  ");
    int n = get_int();
    int counter = 0;

    collatz(n, &counter);
    printf("%i\n",counter);
}

void collatz (int n, int *counter)
{
    if (n == 1)
    {
        *counter++;
        return;
    } else if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        *counter++;
        return collatz(n/2, counter);
    }else if (n % 2 != 0)
    {
        *counter++;
        return collatz((n * 3) + 1, counter);
    }
}
```

When compiled it shows this error on the three times I've used it

```
error: expression result unused [-Werror,-Wunused-value]
            *counter++;
            ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Postfix operators have higher precedence than unary operators. Also, the compiler should have issued a diagnostic about `return` with an expression in a function returning `void`.

Comment: Your question title doesn't match your question.

Comment: `*counter++;` -->> `*counter += 1;` is a trick to avoid parentheses.

Comment: @joop: Why? `++*counter;` has no parentheses either.

Comment: Aside: I don't get why all those `else` statements are there when the `if` code blocks will never reach them, nor why you make the test `if (n % 2 != 0)` when you already established that in the previous conditional.

Comment: @EOF: you are correct, of course. Maybe `+= 1` is easier to read, then?

Comment: @EOF thanks that makes it work but the compiler didn't complain about a return statement, I guess this how recursive functions works

Comment: @YasserAltamimi If the compiler did not issue a diagnostic message about the `return` statements, it is non-conforming. Replace it with a working compiler.

Comment: @joop I guess that's so much easier to understand with all the operators around :) good one thanks

Comment: "the compiler didn't complain about a return statement" - please enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: @EOF well :) I'm actually taking the Harvard cs50 course online on edx, and they force us to work with this cloud compiler for assignment and exercises

Comment: Returning an (int) value instead of void would also allow the compiler to  catch and remove the tail recursion, and avoid passing the pointer.

Comment: @YasserAltamimi Then file a bug report with whoever is responsible. `return` with an expression is a *constraint violation*: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.8.6.4 The return statement
Constraints
1
A return statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type
is void. A return statement without an expression shall only appear in a function
whose return type is void.*

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't get what you mean by the else if will not be reached, suppose m is 5 then if n == 1 will not be executed so is't even? no, then it's odd,, probably I should not write the last else if and leave it only as else is what you meant?

Comment: @YasserAltamimi my point is that each `if` code block ends with `return`, so the following `else` is "code bloat".

Comment: @WeatherVane but it returns to the same function, excuse me for my little knowledge as I'm only a beginner

Comment: It return to the *previous* invocation of the function, not to the *same* instance of the function.

Comment: WeatherVane is right that the `else`es are unneeded, but using them is a perfectly valid stylistic choice.  I myself prefer them in cases such as this, as I find that they make the logic just a bit clearer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am still lost on how would this work without the if else statement ,, could you guys please just give me an example so I can at last imagine how it looks like

Comment: @YasserAltamimi, you can simply remove the two `else` keywords from your `collatz()` function without changing anything else, and it would still perform exactly the same computation.  This is because once control reaches one of the return statements, it returns from (that execution of) the function.  Control exits that scope, and resumes in the caller's scope.  Since the function is recursive, the caller might be a different execution of the same function.

Comment: Ohh that's so confusing haha ,, how would the function know when to divide by 3 and add one and when it has to just divide it by 2?

Answer (score -1):

Pointerless version with tail-recursion.

```
unsigned collatz2(unsigned val)
{
if (val <= 1) return 0;

if (val%2) val = val*3 +1;
else val /= 2;

return 1+collatz2(val);
}
```